# Kendo Html grid filters to linq query

Tags: asp.net-web-api, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo grid and backend in ASP.WebApi

In Kendo Mvc there is the class `DataSourceRequest` and with the extension `ToDataSourceResult` you can filter your datasources with the parameters from the grid in the view.

Now i'm creating an application with HTML5 and Angular. For this solution i don't find a dll provided by Telerik.

Is there a way to easy take in the grid parameters (paging, sorting, filtering) and apply them to my IQueryable datasource?

Comment: kendo datasource requests send all that info to server

Comment: @GeneR yes it does. and you receive that info int he WebApi action, there is must be applied to a datasource to provide filtering sorting and paging. But i don't want to write the entire expression parsing for this.

Comment: i dont see other way than using kendo mvc `ToDataSourceResult` or manually apply sorting, firltering and paging to your IEnumerable result. Btw sorting is applied always in grid on client side.

Comment: @GeneR it is not always applied clientside, you can set this attribute on the grid. It passes all parameter (sorting, filtering, paging) to the server and you have to implement it in your WebApi Action

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to do that:

- Use the [Kendo.DynamicLinq](https://github.com/kendo-labs/dlinq-helpers) open source library
- Use UI for ASP.NET MVC. [There is a help article](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/how-to/web-api-server-operations) that shows how to do that from JavaScript.

Comment: the ASP MVC approach is not valid in my case since we are using HTML and Angular to a WebApi, i will check kendo.DynamicLinq library tonight :) upvote and accept will follow if it works :)